# Dispaying current menu items submenu twentyeleven wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation

I'm using the twentyeleven theme for wordpress 3.4.2. The default theme menu shows a dropdown on hover. What I'd like to do is have the current menu item's submenu displayed. What I've achieved thus far is diplaying the submenu by setting the css property `display:visible`.

This link, http://www.gq.com shows an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

The related CSS styles are as follows:

```
#access {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
}

#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#access li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#access a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    padding: 0 1.2125em;
}

#access ul ul {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.9em;
    left: 0;
    width: 188px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#access ul ul a {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 168px;
}

#access ul li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem with YOUR code? Show us.

Comment: First off, I hope you don't really mean `display:visible`, because that isn't a valid value for that property :-).  Second, could you please get specific about A) what you're currently seeing happen with the above CSS, and B) what you want to happen instead?