# Form submit button not working

Tags: javascript, css, forms, mailchimp, submit-button

I'm using a mailchimp embed code on to generate a pop-up newsletter signup form. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've styled the form and hidden some fields.

Now that its completed it looks like the form submit button won't submit. Any ideas, I've read a number questions and tried to troubleshoot to no avail. 
I haven't picked up any errors in firebug. I think the problem might be css related.

You can view the form on the site , it pops up after a few seconds. Site address is http://www.truechase.co.za.
Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you saying : $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").unbind('submit'); ? This will prevent form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've styled the form and hidden some fields.

Well there (most likely) is your problem :-)  Those fields are probably required by MailChimp, but because you are hiding them with `display:none` they aren't submitting.

Check out this Stack Overflow question for how you can hide the fields *without* losing them when you submit:

[Submit form fields inside display:none element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318428/submit-form-fields-inside-displaynone-element)

Comment: I actually just tried displaying them and the form still didn't submit. Thanks I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Huh; that's weird because when I go to your site the form submission fails and I see "Please enter a value".  Does that message still appear when you expose all your fields (and is there any chance you can share a version without the fields hidden)?

Comment: That message appeared a moment ago when I tried to remove those "extra" fields. So I've now put them back in place and about to look at your initial suggestion.

Comment: Ok, looks like you're right. I've displayed the previously hidden fields. And the form now submits. Now I'll just have to find a way to hide them safely

Comment: Read the link I provided; it describes *exactly* how to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Tried that but didn't submit either. I think it's because those fields are also required fields. I'm going to mailchimp to try and create the form without said fields

Comment: Strange; normally `visibility: hidden` fields still submit with the form.  Another option you could consider is just changing all those inputs to `type='hidden'`; this will make them submit, but not appear.

Comment: I decided it would be a pain to recreate the form in mailchimp. Instead what I've done is deleted the some fields but kept all the required fields. Now it works like a charm. Thanks for all your help machineghost. Much appreciiated. I'm new to the forum. Could you tell me how to close the question?

Comment: Glad I could help.  To close the thread just click the green check-mark outline next to the whichever answer best answered your question (since I've got the only answer in this case, you'd presumably click on the checkmark next to mine).  If you felt it was a particularly good answer you can also optionally upvote  it (click on the up arrow), but only the checkmark/acceptance part is needed to close the question.

Comment: Thanks again. i don't mean to take advantage, but I wonder if you can help with another question of mine. I'm trying to get the menu on the same site not to drop down onhover. What I'd like is a secondary bar with the secondary items pertaining to the current parent displayed.

Comment: A good example would be www.gq.com. My client needs me to replicate this but I'm stumped.

Comment: I'd be happy to try and help, but to keep in the spirit of Stack Overflow (and make it so that any answer you get is easily find-able for others) I strongly recommend asking another, separate question for that.  I'll be skimming the unanswered queue this afternoon though, so I'll probably see it and try to answer it once you do (but who knows, someone else may even beat me to it, and you'll get an answer even faster as a result).

Comment: Well I can point you to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866254/dispaying-current-menu-items-submenu-twentyeleven-wordpress. I'm not great with menus and rely heavily on wp for that.